# Django upload images and place in a directory for each user

Tags: django

I am looking to create a new directory for each user. The code for the model is below, and should look something like this. How do I access the current username that is created during registration? I put a placeholder function getcurrentusername() that should return a string so the directory created for the image is username/profile_images/

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=getcurrentusername()+'\profile_images', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

In forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('picture',)
```

In views.py

```
profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)
...
profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
profile.user = user
    ...
    if 'picture' in request.FILES:
        profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

    profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Method for upload_to have 2 parameters: instance and filename. So you can get your username out of instance like:

```
def getcurrentusername(instance, filename):
    return "/dir/dir/{0}/{1}".format(instance.user.username, filename)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
...
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=getcurrentusername)
```

When Django will save your picture, it will call getcurrentusername and pass it needed parameters.

Comment: The instance is created in the view when the register function is called. How to I pass that information from the view back into the model. I was thinking something like this.
     from main.views import profile
     class UserProfile(modesl.Model):
     picture =    models.ImageField(upload_to=getcurrentusername(profile))

Comment: @ThomasThornier If you are creating instance manually, then could you add view's code to your question?

Comment: Come on, you've cut out the most interesting points out of views.py. Please add view's class and invoked function's definition.